# Create multiple interfaces facing multiple VLANs

Tags: linux, networking, vlan

For several reasons, I need to output tagged traffic from my router to my PC, so that I can access multiple VLANs (and subnets) simultaneously. I need multiple virtual interfaces facing multiple VLAN traffic set up on my PC for it to work.

Can someone guide me how to do that on both Windows 10 and maybe Linux as well?

Comment: This is normally done from a vlan capable router & vlan capable switch, not the end user device.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Are you imagining the PC has multiple physical NICs connected to the switch? If OP's PC only has a single physical NIC connected to the switch, then OP will need to make that switch port a trunk port with tagged VLANs (which maybe they've already done), and OP will still need to do exactly as they asked: set up multiple virtual interfaces, one for each VLAN, on the one physical NIC, so that traffic to each VLAN gets tagged appropriately.

Comment: @spiff, Yep that's exactly what I was talking about. I'm not a Windows guy, at least not win10. My understanding of this is that the nic and drivers in Windows need to support vlan tagging. For this reason, end user stations are usually not "trunked" in this sense. (Not counting phone/data vlans.) Why not routing on a stick? Or layer-3 switching? My interpretation of this is essentially that he was "doing it backwards" to what I would consider normal. It's not exactly a high quality question, so who knows?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I use my PC for managing all network devices, and have a separate VLAN for managing all network equipments. Firewall rules are used to block incoming traffic from other VLANs to the management VLAN. The problem is, my PC also shares some services to users, so it needs to be presence in multiple (at least 2) VLANs silmutaneously. Is there any better solution than this?

Comment: Why not open those services in the firewall?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, you cannot really do this with any built-in tools (except maybe with the Hyper-V "vSwitch" host interfaces). The existing regular Ethernet interface can use a tagged VLAN however.

Some Ethernet NIC drivers (e.g. Intel's server-oriented NICs) have their own custom control panels which allow creating multiple tagged interfaces.

On Linux, use `ip link` for temporary configurations:

```
ip link add eth0.10 link eth0 type vlan id 10
ip link set eth0.10 up
```

(Note: The `eth0.<vid>` naming convention is not mandatory – the actual VID is specified as a separate parameter. However, some tools such as Debian's ifupdown *may* use this to automatically detect the VID if you did not specify it separately.)

(Note 2: You can specify `protocol 802.1ad` to use a Service VLAN tag.)

On FreeBSD:

```
ifconfig em0.5 create vlandev em0 vlan 5
ifconfig em0.5 up
```